Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Awaited<R>'.(2339)
The generic parameters of the request function are same with the axios.request() method.
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

async function request<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(config: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<R> {
    const r = await axios.request<T, R>(config);
    return r;
}

async function json<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(config: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<T> {
    const response = await request<T, R>(config);
    return response.data;  // TSC throws error here
}

I expect that the TS type of response should be AxiosResponse, but the actual type is Awaited<R>. I also expect the type of response.data should be T(AxiosResponse['data']).
TS Playground

Why use R at all? https://tsplay.dev/mpk0bN

I swear I've seen this exact question before. In short, you're trying too hard with the generics

Found it. Duplicate - Awaited is not being unwrapped to R with response object

The type parameter R is only defaulted to AxiosResponse<T>. If you call json with a different type in that position, then there might not be a data member.
The type parameter R extends AxiosResponse<T> = AxiosResponse<T> would be more appropriate.
Playground link

EDIT: @Caleth's answer address the specific issue you're having.
Here's a simplified version of your code that solves the issue:
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

async function request<T>(config: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<AxiosResponse<T>> {
    const r = axios.request<T, AxiosResponse<T>>(config);
    return r;
}

async function json<T>(config: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<T> {
    const response = await request<T>(config);
    return response.data;
}

TS Playground
